# Is this how one passes a method of a Parent component to a child in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a section of a book I am coding along with it explains how a child component would get access to a parents methods.

> The way to communicate from the child to a parent is by passing callbacks from the parent to the child, which it can call to achieve specific tasks. In this case, you pass createIssue as a callback property from IssueTable to IssueAdd. From the child, you just call the passed in function in your handler to create a new issue.

The author mentions `IssueTable` (sibling) to `IssueAdd`(sibling) he probably meant `IssueList` (parent) to `IssueAdd`(child)—right?

I would think just by examining the return `JSX` from `IssueList`...

We could see `IssueTable` is sibling to `IssueAdd`, no?

```
const contentNode = document.getElementById('contents');

class IssueFilter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        This is placeholder for the Issue Filter.{this.props.name}
        {this.props.age}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const IssueRow = props => (
  <tr>
    <td>{props.issue.id}</td>
    <td>{props.issue.status}</td>
    <td>{props.issue.owner}</td>
    <td>{props.issue.created.toDateString()}</td>
    <td>{props.issue.effort}</td>
    <td>{props.issue.completionDate ? props.issue.completionDate.toDateString() : ''}</td>
    <td>{props.issue.title}</td>
  </tr>
);

function IssueTable(props) {
  const issueRows = props.issues.map(issue => <IssueRow key={issue.id} issue={issue} />);
  return (
    <table className="bordered-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Owner</th>
          <th>Created</th>
          <th>Effort</th>
          <th>Completion Date</th>
          <th>Title</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>{issueRows}</tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

class IssueAdd extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = document.forms.issueAdd;
    console.log('form', document.forms);
    this.props.createIssue({
      owner: form.owner.value,
      title: form.title.value,
      status: 'New',
      created: new Date()
    });
    //clear the form for the next input
    form.owner.value = '';
    form.title.value = '';
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form name="issueAdd" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text" name="owner" placeholder="Owner" />
          <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" />
          <button>Add</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class IssueList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { issues: [] };
    this.createIssue = this.createIssue.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadData();
  }

  loadData() {
    fetch('/api/issues')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log('Total count of records:', data._metadata.total_count);
        data.records.forEach(issue => {
          issue.created = new Date(issue.created);
          if (issue.completionDate) issue.completionDate = new Date(issue.completionDate);
        });
        this.setState({ issues: data.records });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  createIssue(newIssue) {
    fetch('/api/issues', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(newIssue)
    })
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          response.json().then(updatedIssue => {
            updatedIssue.created = new Date(updatedIssue.created);
            if (updatedIssue.completionDate) updatedIssue.completionDate = new Date(updatedIssue.completionDate);
            const newIssues = this.state.issues.concat(updatedIssue);
            this.setState({ issues: newIssues });
          }); //**/
        } else {
          response.json().then(error => {
            alert('Failed to add issue: ' + error.message);
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        alert('Error in sending data to server: ' + err.message);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Issue Tracker</h1>
        <IssueFilter />
        <hr />
        <IssueTable issues={this.state.issues} />
        <hr />
        <IssueAdd createIssue={this.createIssue} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<IssueList />, contentNode);
```

So in short all one has to do to leverage a function declared in a parent  is the following....?

```
const contentNode = document.getElementById('contents');


class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
        this.props.someFunc; //So naming this prop someFunc will just help us identify this prop should get the function from the parent?
  }
}

class Parent extends React.component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
        this.someFunc = this.someFunc.bind(this);
  }

  someFunc(){
   ....
  }

   render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ChildComponent someFunc={this.someFunc} /> // Parent's someFunc gets passed as a value to the ChildComponent's prop which is someFunc?
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, contentNode);
```

Comment: The way the components are laid out, the description you posted is wrong and you are right: the createIssue callback is passed from IssueList to IssueAdd.

Comment: The children of IssueList are: IssueFilter, IssueTable, and IssueAdd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `IssueTable` and `IssueAdd` are in fact siblings from the code snippet you posted.

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
        this.props.someFunc; //So naming this prop someFunc will just help us identify this prop should get the function from the parent?
  }
}
```

In the above snippet this.props.someFunc will not serve any purpose, it will just return the function which you sent from `ParentComponent` but nothing will happen.

If you are planning to modify or change parent's state from an action in the `ChildComponent` then the below snippet might make more sense.

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);         
   }

  handleOnClick = (event) => {
     // The name is someFunc because that is what you sent as props from the 
     // ParentComponent <ChildComponent someFunc={this.someFunc} />

     // If it had been <ChildComponent callbackToParent={this.someFunc} /> 
     // then you should access the function as this.props.callbackToParent 
     // and invoke as this.props.callbackToParent()

     this.props.someFunc();  
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.handleOnClick}>
        Click to trigger callback sent by parent
      </div>
    ) 
  }
}
```